# What is the difference between aula and atrium?

Tags: word-comparison, greek, architecture

When researching for the [living room question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2272/79) and the question that inspired it, I came across some dictionary definitions of [*aula*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2005594) and [*atrium*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2005327).
*Aula* is a Greek thing and *atrium* is Roman, but otherwise they seem very similar to me.

I know there are architectural differences between Greece and Rome.
**What is the difference between *aula* and *atrium*?**
I have found no comparison of the two anywhere.
**Would the Romans use the word *atrium* for something the Greeks would call *aula* and vice versa?**
I get the impression that *atrium* is the Roman-style word for an inner court or a hall, and *aula* is a Greek-style word for the same purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**General description of a Greek αυλη:**

An *αυλη* could refer to a courtyard in front of the house or a courtyard, open to the sky, within the house, around which rooms were located.  This courtyard was surrounded on all four sides with colonnades, creating a peristyle.  These were used for exercise mainly but occasionally meals were eaten here.  The household altar of Zeus was also located in the *αυλη*.

**General description of a Roman atrium:**

The Roman *atrium* was the first main room into which guests entered from the front door.  In early Roman houses, the *atrium* was the only room.  As wealth increased, so did the number of rooms, all of which led off the *atrium* but the *atrium* remained the most important room.  It was open to the sky, allowing rainwater to collect in the *impluvium*.  The household gods, the *Lares*, were kept here, as were the wax portraits of family ancestors, and the *lectus genialis*.  Its main and most important function was to receive clients and guests.  As such, *atria* could be very elaborate and were an important part of displaying and maintaining status.

**Similarities between a Greek αυλη and a Roman atrium:**

Open to the sky.

Rooms were located off this centralised space.

Religious icons were kept here.

**Differences between a Greek αυλη and a Roman atrium:**

The *αυλη* seems to have always been a courtyard at heart, that is to say, an outdoor area.  In contrast, the *atrium* was always a room (in early houses, the only room).

The *αυλη* was surrounded on four sides with colonnades creating a peristyle or cloister which was used for exercise.  Indeed, Vitruvius appears to use *aula* and *peristylium* synonymously (6.7.4).  The *[Dictionary of Greek and Roman Antiquities](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0063%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DD%3Aentry%3Ddomus-cn&force=y)* similarly notes that *αυλη* was “also used by later writers as equivalent to *περιστύλιον*”, citing Pollux (who wrote in 2nd cent. AD).

In contrast, Vitruvius distinguishes between *peristylium* and *atrium* in the Roman house (6.5.2 – see below).  For Vitruvius, therefore, neither *αυλη* nor *aula* are the same as *atrium*.  The *atrium* had columns, no doubt to support the roof, but I have found no evidence that they were employed to create a colonnade nor that the *atrium* was used for exercise.  Rather, the *atrium* appears to be a much more enclosed space than the *αυλη*.  I’m not sure just how open to the sky each space was.  It seems that the *αυλη* was entirely open while the atrium had *an* opening, the *compluvium*, to allow rainwater to run into the *impluvium*.

The *atrium* was first and foremost a room for receiving clients/guests.  A crowded *atrium* signified great social and political success (*frequens atrium* – Seneca, *Epistles*, 76.12); an empty one, failure (*atrium vacuum* – Seneca, *Epistles*, 22.9).  I have not come across *aula* (in Latin) being used in this way, to denote a room in which one’s social status hangs in the balance.

Vitruvius goes so far as to say that those in the lower classes do not need an *atrium* since they don’t receive clients (but rather are clients) (6.5.1).  On the other hand, those of the highest rank have need of lofty *atria*:

> *faciunda sunt vestibula regalia, alta atria et peristylia amplissima*
>   (6.5.2)

Note again Vitruvius’ distinction between *atrium* and *peristylium*, the latter of which he sees as synonymous with *aula*.  Later, he clarifies that in the Greek house:

> *hospites advenientes **non** in peristylia sed in ea hospitalia
>   recipiantur* / arriving guests are **not** received in the peristylia but
>   in the guest accommodation (6.7.4)

Thus, the **function** of the *aula* and the *atrium* are not at all the same.  In very early Greek houses, the *αυλη* was a courtyard you would pass through on your way to the *δωμα* or *μεγαρον*, the great hall.  This reinforces the idea that the *αυλη* was not the main reception room in the Greek house ([see this diagram of Odysseus' palace](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/image?img=Perseus:image:1999.04.0063.fig10658)).

As Vitruvius wrote:

> *atriis graeci quia non utuntur, neque aedificiant …* / not using atria,
>   the Greeks do not build like us … (6.7.1)

**But how did the Romans use the (Latin) terms aula and atrium?**

By far the most common use of *aula* in Latin is to mean court, as in the sense of a ruler’s entourage and household, or simply a palace.

Nevertheless, the Romans did sometimes use *aula* to mean a forecourt, usually where animals were kept, for instance a barking dog in Horace (*Epistles*, 1.2.66) and sheep in Propertius (3.13.39).  Thus, this use equates with one Greek sense of the word.

Otherwise, it is hard to be 100% certain that *aula* was used synonymously with *atrium*.  As noted above, Vitruvius doesn’t use *aula* and *atrium* interchangeably as he clearly sees the two terms as describing two quite different spaces, different in form and function.

However, Horace’s use of *aula* (in *Epistles*, 1.1.87) is clearly being used as a synonym with *atrium*.  I say this because of the reference to the *lectus genialis*, the marriage bed which was kept in the *atrium* (unoccupied!), opposite the front door ([lectus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0063%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DL%3Aentry%20group%3D1%3Aentry%3Dlectus-cn)).

Another possible synonymous use of *aula* with *atrium* is in Juvenal (*Satires*, 1.5) where he advises someone not to have children lest they divert his attentions from his patron:

> *nullus tibi parvulus aula luserit Aeneas* / don’t have a little Aeneas
>   playing in the *aula*

[which is actually a reference to Dido’s lament:
*si quis mihi parvulus aula luderet Aeneas* /
if in my *aula* a baby Aeneas were playing (*Aeneid*, 4:328)]

Juvenal (and Dido) may mean the *atrium* or the *aula* proper, a peristyle or they could just as easily mean the forecourt.  The problem is that, when translating, you could equally insert hall/atrium/courtyard and still make perfect sense without ever knowing for sure what the original intention was.

Having said that, it seems to me that when it is important to the understanding of the sentence, *atrium* is used.  For example, the biting remarks of Seneca about the gap between appearances and reality relies on the reader understanding that he is talking about the atrium and its function as a marker of status:

> *non facit nobilem atrium plenum fumosis imaginibus* / an atrium full of
>   busts grimy with smoke do not make a nobleman (*Epistles* 44.5)

Or again in Juvenal:

> *tota licet veteres exornent undique cerae atria, nobilitas sola est
>   atque unica virtus* / you may decorate your entire atrium everywhere
>   with ancient wax portraits but the one and only nobility is excellence
>   of character (*Satires*, 8.19).

And in Horace:

> *cur invidendis postibus et novo sublime ritu moliar atrium?* / why
>   should I go to all the effort to build envy-inducing doorposts and a
>   towering atrium? (*Odes*, 3.1.45-46)

I don’t think that in any of these examples the full force of the author’s point would be felt if they had used *aula*.  This is, in my opinion, because the perceived **functions** of the *aula/αυλη* and the *atrium* were different even if over time all three terms came to suggest the **form** of a central hall-like space.  Only the distinctly Roman atrium and its peculiarly Roman function as reception room could be used here.

Comment: I'm very glad to see your references to Smith's Dictionary of Greek & Roman Antiquities. It's a remarkable source, one which unfortunately seems to have fallen into disregard, and a compilation undertaken by a truly remarkable scholar.

Answer (score 8):

The *atrium* was a central, and most important part of the Roman *domus*, built as a kind of courtyard. It had an inwardly-sloping roof with a central gap  — the *impluvium*, into which rainwater drained before falling into a cistern (which, confusingly, was also called *impluvium*). Vitruvius (vi, 3) is a major source for the various designs, etc., of *atrium*, which he also refers to as *cavum aedium*.

The word *aula* is less easily defined. Though in origin it was a court in the front of a Greek house, it doesn't seem to have been anything at Rome as important to a house as the *atrium* itself, but was possibly some part of it (Horace Ep. I, 1, 87). The word seems just as likely to have been used for 'court' in all the English senses of the noun, (e.g. Tacitus Hist. I, 13, *end*)